# Python - Присоединение к строке

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем ошибка:
В результате кода название +черта(|)+ звезды(*) должны оказаться на одно строке, как показано ниже:

```
Слёзы радости |**********************************************
```

Но, в результате кода, звезды переходят на следующую строку:

```
Слёзы радости   |
**********************************************
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Код ниже:

```
for row in data:
        # Название с выравниванием
        print ('{: <16}|'.format(row[0], end=''))
        # Вычислить длину столбца, один символ * = 5 млн(с округлением вниз)
        length= row[1]/5
        # сделайте цикл для печати символа * нужное число раз
        for i in range (int (length)):
            print ('*', end='')
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас параметр `end` для первого принта написан не в той паре скобок.

```
print('{: <16}|'.format(row[0]), end='')
```